# What is the role of "enc-dec-train-roto-ptrs.txt" in ROTOWIRE dataset?

Tags: datatable, nlp, dataset

I'm dealing with table-to-text task with ROTOWIRE Dataset.

I've faced some problem with dataset, which is used in [this research.](https://github.com/ernestgong/data2text-three-dimensions)

As you could see in the github dataset link, there is a "enc-dec-train-roto-ptrs.txt" file which is used in preprocessing. I have no idea what this  "enc-dec-train-roto-ptrs.txt" is for, which only consists of numbers. Is it about numbers about each game record or something? I would be really greatful if someone who knows about this let me know it.

Additionally, I have one more question about what does "roto_train-beam5_gens.h5-tuples.txt" and "train_content_plan.txt" is for and how it is made.

Thank you!